# I don't understand how email activation works

Tags: c#, email-validation

I want to verify that the user email is valid and turn this email into his id in my system.
Yet I don't know how to make a link in the mail, that activates the account like(facebook and others
) and I don't really understand what happens when the link is selected.

I thought of generating a key like "sdklbsdgk4493" to enter once- so that guessing is hard, yet for many people copy and paste is not trivial and I may annoy them with this solution.

Any thoughts or ideas?

p.s: I'm working in c# so if it can be done with c#... it will be great :)

Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you insert a new user in the Database, their status should be "Deactivated" and you insert a "GUID" you generate alongside. You send them a link to your activation Page which would contain this GUID in the Query String. It will look like this:

`www.YourSite.com/Activation.aspx?GUID=jdfhg43h98234`

In the `Activation.aspx` page, you take this GUID from the Query String and compare it to the one you have in the Database. You then activate the Account having that GUID.

Comment: To minimize chance of cheating, you better add the email itself (encoded) to the URL then make sure the user is activating his own email and not just guessing the GUID. Also, set expire date on this, for example after two days the activation link won't be available anymore.

Comment: So the trick is in the query string of the URL...the user just browse to a regular webpage and this page grubs the GUID parameter from the URL and than perform the DB work with this parameter... Sound great yet I don't understand how it's possible to create unique random keys over time without repeating them... in theory a user can try to activate his account a year after he got his mail (and by a long shot someone else can get the same random key)?

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard : it's not the user that worries me - it's the system. example: I give a user a key 1234 after 2 days he does not activate and I delete his temp account. after a year another user gets a key 1234 and by change the first user decide to press his old mail activation key: he activates the wrong account... yet encrypting the email should solve the problem(I really need to learn about encryption-I know very little of it.) Thanks

Comment: @Asaf look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx for a method of generating "almost" unique GUID objects. Using that you shouldn't have to worry about duplicates unless your system is seeing huge amounts of traffic.

Comment: @Asaf: if you're using GUIDs, it's a lot more than "a long shot", no matter how much traffic you're seeing. A GUID is a 128-bit number. There are 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 different possibilities.

Comment: @Asaf - yes, the trick is using the URL. In C# creating totally unique value is as simple as this: `string uniqueKey = (Guid.NewGuid()).ToString("N");` this will generate totally unique 32 characters key that will never repeat itself. To avoid having the user activating it after one year, add another column where you'll store the time in which the key was generated, and if trying to activate this key after x days, simply ignore this. Encryption: actually you better use Hash, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx

Comment: its really hard even imposable to guess a GUID.

Comment: @Arrabi - correct but still.. personally I prefer to play it safe.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create the user
2. Generate a unique string for the user
3. Have a Table that stores the unique string, the user Id ,a boolean that holds whether it got activated or not, the generation date, the expiration date and if you have different uses for these activation strings, the type(link to another table)
4. Now within the email you should get the string and write it within the email along with a link to the page you're going to use for validation such as whatever.com/verify.aspx?activationString=hd3fd33fen342n43
5. Within this page you do a query search within the table that holds the keys and if its not already validated

Answer (score 2):

You have your users table in the DB (or where ever it is that you store your list of users), just add a column stating if the user's mail is validated.
To the validation mail add a link that fires some PHP with a user-specific code (like it's index in the DB). The PHP will set the user's "validated" column to true, and it'll be done.

It's not as complicated as it may seem at first.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a random key, save it to the database connected to the useraccount, supplying a link to the users e-mail which could point to a webservice(or regular website) which takes the key as a querystring which will then activate the account connected to that specific key.